# Como puedo organizar de manera descendente un array de floats en Java

Tags: java, array, float, ordenar

Uso un método para ordenar de manera ascendente un **array de *floats*** con *Arrays.sort(myArr)* que funciona, ahora necesito otro método que me ordene inversamente el mismo array que se le pasa como parámetro.

He estado mirando varias propuestas en foros pero ninguna me ha servido de momento para aplicar al array de tipo *float*, he visto que la más común es la siguiente (Aunque tampoco me sirve ya que trabaja con el tipo primitivo *Integer*):

```
public static float[] ordenarInversamente(float[] myArr) {
    
    Arrays.sort(myArr, Collections.reverseOrder());
            
    return myArr;
}
```

Comment: Esto te sirve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354326/java-how-to-sort-an-array-of-floats-in-reverse-order

Comment: agrega ejemplo de los datos que piensas procesar para sugerirte algo que se adapte mejor a tus necesidades particulares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es que el método `Arrays.sort con Collections.reverseOrder()` no funcione con float, si analizamos el método sort que muestras el código seria:

```
    public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
        if (c == null) {
            sort(a); <------- método en uso
        } else {
            if (LegacyMergeSort.userRequested)
                legacyMergeSort(a, c);
            else
                TimSort.sort(a, 0, a.length, c, null, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Aquí podemos ver que hace uso de Genéricos `T[]` y además llama el método `sort(a);` el cual corresponde a `public static void sort(Object[] a)` con esto podemos concluir que el método espera un array de Objetos y estas enviado un array de primitivos (Float -> Object y float -> primitivo).

Las opciones que se me ocurren serian:

1. Pasar de un array de float a array de Float.

```
public static float[] ordenarInversamente(Float[] myArr) {
    
    Arrays.sort(myArr, Collections.reverseOrder());
            
    return myArr;
}
```

2. Hacer un sort y después invertir por código el orden

```
public static float[] ordenarInversamente(float[] myArr) {
    
    Arrays.sort(myArr);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArr));

       // Lo que haremos es ir intercambiando las posiciones por eso si recorremos el arreglo hasta la mitad
       // ya habremos intercambiado todas las posiciones
     for (int i = 0; i < myArr.length / 2; i++) {
         float temporal = myArr[i];
         // Obtenemos el valor de la posición equivalente al lado contrario y lo insertamos en la posición del temporal
         myArr[i] = myArr[myArr.length - i - 1];
         // Ahora sustituimos el valor en el temporal al lado contrario
         myArr[myArr.length - i - 1] = temporal;
      }
            
    return myArr;
}
```

El ordenamiento inverso de forma grafica seria:

```
Array Inicial Ordenado:  [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 20.0, 100.0]
Primera Iteración:       [100.0, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 20.0, 1.1]
Segunda Iteración:       [100.0, 20.0, 3.3, 4.4, 2.2, 1.1]
Tercera Iteración:       [100.0, 20.0, 4.4, 3.3, 2.2, 1.1]
Cuarta Iteración:        [100.0, 20.0, 4.4, 3.3, 2.2, 1.1]
```

Tenia pensado hacerlo con Arrays.stream pero no tengo una repuesta a porque no esta imprentado el soporte para arrays de `float` solo existe para `double` en tipo de dato con decimales.